# How to upload saved video to a remote server, captured using cordovaCapture?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using the captureVideo method of cordovaCapture as follows:

```
$cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options)
  .then(function(videoData) {
    var file_path = videoData[0].fullPath;
   // upload to server
});
```

I get the file path as

> file:/storage/....mp4

How to upload this file to a remote server, will I be able to access this file directly through my controller or will I have to process a url out of it?

I am using the Ionic framework.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the file upload plugin: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/ to upload it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is pretty simple. This will work only in ionic FW

first you must be installed file transfer plugin. if not use this command:

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer`

assume http://www.samplewebsite.com/upload. is your server hyperlink.

```
example.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaFileTransfer) {

    $scope.upload = function() {
        var options = {
            fileKey: "avatar",
            fileName: "filename.mp4",
            chunkedMode: false,
            mimeType: "video/mp4"
        };
        $cordovaFileTransfer.upload("http://www.samplewebsite.com/upload", "file:/storage/....mp4", options).then(function(result) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        }, function (progress) {
            // constant progress updates
        });
    }

});
```

after all you need to call this function like this

```
<button class="button" ng-click="upload()">video upload</button>
```

Its working. I have done many times.

Comment: Thanks, tried this and it worked. This plugin is not as well documented in ngCordova as it is in the Github link.

Comment: @Prabhu:How to upload local files from our storage media?

Comment: Helpful answer.
My question is using cordova I have to open gallery popup and select video and upload it. I am doing this using $cordovaCamera.getPicture and providing "options->mediaType-: navigator.camera.MediaType.VIDEO"

hardluck I can see the path of video in the adb logcat :/storage/emulated/0/Video/abcd.3gp but file is getting uploaded.

Comment: i tried this. but get the error from server as 405 status

Comment: how would you find the `mimeType` since phone camera videos can have different mime types, such as mp4, mov, etc.